# iOS - tabBar item inset doesnt work

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I adjust the size, but does not work.

[image]

[image]
These are from Storyboard

[image]
This is from Simulator.

Comment: I can't repro this. Can you provide some code to an isolated project to reproduce this?

Comment: There is no code for this. Just set the image inset. It looks good on Storyboard but doesnt work for Simulator.